# c use libcurl curl_easy_perform post, spaces and dot replaced by underscore

Tags: c, libcurl

c use libcurl curl_easy_perform post, spaces and dot replaced by underscore

The code is like the example below.

On the other side the received data is wrong:

Expect: `<Text>data to send...</Text>`

Actually: `<Text>data_to_send___</Text>`

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    const char *data = "<Text>data to send...</Text>";
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
}
```

Does anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an incorrect conclusion so the question ends up rather useless.

libcurl will send the data *exactly* as you provide it with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. If the data end up looking different in some presentation layer of yours, then it was either changed or displayed like that by some other layer/software component.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,yes you are right it was because I did not set the httpheader ,but the destination only accept xml!  ! So this issue happened!